# How to do calculated values in Excel Pivot Table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a table like this:

```
Year       Num  Freq.   Exam    Grade   Course
2014    102846  SM              SM      Astronomy 3
2015    102846  12,6    1,7     NC      Astronomy 2
2017    102846  20      11,8    17      Astronomy 2
2015    102846  SM              NC      Defence Against the Dark Arts 4
2015    102846  11      4,5     NC      Herbology 2
2015    102846  15      13,99   14      Herbology 2
```

I am trying to get the percentage of approved students (Grade >= 10) for each course by year and global average.
I've been trying for nearly 3 hours to do a calculated field but so far the only thing I could get was the sum of each student per year:
[image]

I have tried to do a calculated field with `= Grade >= 10` hoping that it would give me a list of approved students but it gives me 1.

[image]
What am I doing wrong in here? It's my first time working with pivot tables.

Comment: Does field `Grade` contains only numeric values? Because in the data you posted as example, it does not

Comment: No it can contain letters or even be empty. In both of these it means he is not approved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would really recommend to not mix string type (text) together with numbers. It's a horrifying idea and will cause a lot of headache when data will be used for calculations (both `Freq.` and `Grade`). Rather I would use 0 or some numeric value to represent the text.

Not recommended, but yes it's doable =)

You need some dummy variable to point out which row is number and which is text. So I created `Grade Type`. We can now count only the rows that have a number in the Grade column by using `Grade Type = Number`.

I create a table of the data and add the column `Grade Type`. I use this formula to get `Grade Type`:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER([@Grade]),"Number","Text")
```

I then create the following measures:

**Nr of Approved Students**

```
=COUNTX(FILTER(Table1, Table1[Grade Type]="Number"), 
IF((VALUE(Table1[Grade])>=10),VALUE(Table1[Grade]),BLANK()))
```

First we filter which rows that should be evaluated (`COUNTX(<table>,...)`). If yes, then only count for rows that fulfill `>=10`, where `VALUE()` converts string number to numeric (`COUNTX(...,<expression>)`).

**Nr of Student (w/ Grade Number)**

```
=COUNTX(FILTER(Table1, Table1[Grade Type]="Number"), VALUE(Table1[Grade]))
```

Count all rows that have a number

**Approved (% of Total)**

```
=[Nr of Approved Students]/[Count of Grade]
```

---

**Setup the PowerPivot Table**

Create the PowerPivot and add the data to the data Model
[image]

Then create a new measure by clicking your pivot table and then "Measures" -> "New Measure..."
Fill in all the relevant data.
[image]

Result should be something like:
[image]

Comment: Nice answer and explanation